# How can I get the Facebook ID of someone with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am developing a small python code and I need to know how I can automate the process of going from the URL of a Facebook profile to your ID.

For example, the facebook of Sony is "https://facebook.com/Sony" but the ID is "56232316996" (https://facebook.com/56232316996) (vía https://www.findmyfbid.com).

How can I automate this process using python code?

Huge thanks.

Comment: Why don't you start writting some code? If you get stuck at some point you can ask a question. As it is i'm voting to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

I've try to do the same just recently. This simple program probably works for you.

```py
import requests
def get_fbid(fb_url):
    URL = "https://findmyfbid.com/"
    PARAMS = {'url': fb_url}
    try:
        r = requests.post(url = URL, params= PARAMS)
        return r.json().get("id")
    except Exception:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

How far along in the process are you? Here are some steps to start you off:

1. Register for a Facebook developer account and create a new app. 
   http://developer.facebook.com
2. Use access tokens to authenticate your application to use your Facebook account.
3. Write the Python code that will interface with the application.

Here is a reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-facebook-graph-api-and-extract-data-using-python-1839e19d6999

-Yuriy

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky and needs requests and BeautifulSoup, but works for me:

```
pip install requests  # might not need this
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and then

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fbUrl='https://facebook.com/761051684025235'
r = requests.get(fbUrl)
if r.ok:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  for link in soup.find_all('link'):
    if 'facebook.com' in link.get('href'):
      fbHandle = link.get('href').split('/')[-1]
      print(fbHandle)
      break
```