# How to get a Facebook user ID using post request in python?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to get a specific user id via their username. Can anybody help me with this one?
Here is what I've tried:

```
import requests
import json

def get_fbid(url_face):
    find_fbid = "https://findmyfbid.in/"
    URL = {'url': url_face}
    r = requests.post(url = find_fbid, params = URL)
    return r.json().get("id")
 
print(get_fbid("https://facebook.com/zuck"))
```

This is my first time posting question on stackoverflow, if there any wrong format or it is hard for you to understand, I'm sorry. And here is what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(get_fbid("https://facebook.com/zuck"))
  File "main.py", line 9, in get_fbid
    return r.json().get("id")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 866, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396944/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-id-of-someone-with-python

Comment: I tried that one, and it shows me that error